# String manipulation, subString() method which modifies the original String

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

The problem may be silly, but I couldn't find an answer on google.

Question : Is there any method in StringBuffer or StringBuilder or String itself, which does the same as subString(int startIndex, int endIndex), but modifies the original String ?

For example :

```
StringBuffer testString = new StringBuffer ("myTestString");
StringBuffer subString = testString.newSubStringMethod(0,1);
Sysout(testString);
Sysout(subString);
```

The output I wish to be printed is:

```
TestString
my
```

If not,  what are things to be taken care, when we implement our own implementation of such a method.

Comment: +1 Good question. Just out of curiosity - what do you need it for? A copy is usually cheap anyway.

Comment: @dark_charlie Sorry for the late reply.I was typing reply for your question and my sentences itself gave me an insight that my design was wrong. I went and refactored the entire String processing logic. That is a long story anyway. But now I don't want a `subStringMethodThatDoesntExist()` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve similar result with [StringBuffer#delete](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#delete%28int,%20int%29) or [StringBuilder#delete](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: wouldn't this solution end up printing `TestString` twice, which isn't what OP wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the question in a simple string. For this suppose you declare a `string s` so just write:

```
s = subString(int startIndex, int endIndex);
//this is because a string is immutable
```